# Change README to Readme.md on Github

Tags: github

When I created a project on github, I setup a README file, which now appears on the project page. I've decided to switch to Readme.md so I can add some formatting, but github is still displaying the original README file. I've tried deleting the README and deleting both README and Readme.md and then re-adding Readme.md, but the original README is still on the project page.

https://github.com/toxygene/pale

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could be a cache issue, because the source code of your GitHub project page includes:

````
<!-- readme cache key: tree-readme:2188350:07c93010a313c998bb0d7c69f54b7d50525ca75e -->
<div id="readme" class="clearfix announce instapaper_body ">
  <span class="name"><span class="mini-icon mini-icon-readme"></span> README</span>
  <div class="plain"><pre># Pale

Pale is a simple PHP library that allows a developer to easily convert errors to exceptions without having to worry about the details of changing and restoring error handlers.

## Usage
```php
use Pale;
try {
    Pale\run(function() {
        trigger_error(&quot;this will become an exception&quot;);
    });
} catch(ErrorException $e) {
    var_dump($e);
}
```
</pre></div>
````

The "`cache key: tree-readme:2188350:07c9301...`" suggests the content of that page could be updated in the next following hours.

Comment: It took 48 hours, but it did finally switch to using the Readme.md file.

Comment: @Toxygene darn... that is long. Maybe it is related to their recent issues? (https://status.github.com/messages: **December 12, 2012**
`13:53 UTC We are investigating issues reaching GitHub.com`, 
**December 11, 2012** 
`23:36 UTC We have determined the cause of the outage and are in the process of applying the fix.`, 
`23:09 UTC Our API is currently down. More details soon.`, ...)